# Branching process Galton Watson

Tags: probability, probability-generating-fn, branching

Using the Galton Watson branching process

> Assume that a fox had 0,1,2,3 offspring with probabilities p0,p1,p2,p3 respectively. find the probability distribution for G1 and G2.

[image]I worked out G1 however I’m having difficulty with G2 and I am not able to get my head round it.